# Tomcat always gives 404

Tags: html, tomcat, gwt, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to deploy a Google-Web-Toolkit web application on my tomcat. It works in Eclipse Hosted mode, it works on XAMPP without the rpc calls but on tomcat it doesn't even find the HTML.

Before anything happens I always gets

localhost:8080/test.html

the requested resource (/test.html) is not available.

Even when I just put a HelloWorld.html in the webapps folder I can't display it. What am I missing?

Comment: Does http://localhost:8080/ show a Tomcat welcome page?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your webapp inside another folder inside the 'webapps' folder, then navigate to http://localhost:8080/foldername/test.html.